# Short online videos that could assist a lecture on statistics

Tags: teaching, references

When lecturing statistics, it can be useful to incorporate the occasional short video.

My first thoughts included:

1. Animations and visualisations of statistical concepts
2. Stories regarding the application of a particular technique
3. Humorous videos that have relevance to a statistical idea
4. Interviews with a statistician or a researcher who uses statistics

Are there any videos that you use when teaching statistics or that you think would be useful?

Please provide:

- Link to the video online
- Description of content
- To what statistical topic the video might relate

Comment: Great question!!

Answer (score 11):

Link:

https://yihui.name/animation/

A big list of animation "clips" (gif's or other formats), through the use of the "[animation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html)" package (R).  Including the following topics:

**Topics**(in each of them there are 1 or more animation, by topic)

- Theory of Probability
- Mathematical Statistics
- Sampling Survey
- Linear Models
- Multivariate Statistics
- Nonparametric Statistics (no videos yet)
- Computational Statistics
- Time Series Analysis
- Data Mining, Machine Learning
- Statistical Data Analysis
- R Graphics
- Package ''animation''
- Dynamic Graphics

Through the use of the package, the animations can be reproduced in various formats (such as gif, aws, and others)

Answer (score 6):

ASA Sections on: Statistical Computing Statistical Graphics has a video library:

- http://stat-graphics.org/movies/

It contains a large number of interesting videos relevant to statistical computing and graphics. The videos go back as far as the 1960s.

Comment: Although most of them don't seem relevant for the OP questions, still, this is a nice link - thanks Jeromy!

Answer (score 4):

[BIOSTATISTICS VS. LAB RESEARCH](http://www.xtranormal.com/watch/6878253/):
A funny/sad video on statistics consulting.

Answer (score 4):

This is a great short video about trend VS the variation around it:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0vj-0imOLw

Comment: Very nice short video

Answer (score 3):

In the category (3) of humorous videos, check out ['Statz rappers'](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=489221653835413043#); general interest.  (Pretty funny even to older people ;-).)

Answer (score 3):

http://datajournalism.stanford.edu/ : Video on visualisation

Comment: Really nice, too bad I'm working with medical journals that are stuck in the paper format. +1 for inspiration